# Set density in $X$ and $X \times X$ coimplication

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a (complete) metric space, does a dense set on $X \times X$ imply a dense set on $X$ (and vice versa)?

PS: I do know it's a pretty general question, but I'm willing to improve it if needed

Comment: Do you mean: $D$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $D\times D$ is dense in $X\times X$?

Comment: Exactly @ArcticChar (sorry for my lacunous wording)

Comment: If $D$ is dense in $X \times X$, both $\pi_1[D]$ and $\pi_2[D]$ are dense in $X$ by simple continuity of both projections. If $D$ is dense in $X$, trivially $D \times D$ is dense in $X \times X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true for any space $X$, not just complete metric spaces. Recall that a subset $D$ of a topological space $X$ is dense if and only if for every nonempty open set $U \subseteq X,$ the intersection $D \cap U$ is nonempty.

First, we'll prove that if $D$ is dense in $X$, then $D \times D$ is dense in $X \times X$. Suppose that $D$ is dense in $X$, and let $U \subseteq X \times X$ be an arbitrary nonempty open set. Then, it must contain some basis element for the product topology on $X \times X,$ hence there exists nonempty open sets $U_{1}, U_{2} \subseteq X$ such that $U_{1} \times U_{2} \subseteq U.$ Since $D$ is dense, $U_{1} \cap D$ and $U_{2} \cap D$ are both nonempty, hence $(U_{1} \times U_{2}) \cap (D \times D)$ is nonempty. Clearly, $U \cap (D \times D)$ must also be nonempty, hence $D \times D$ is dense in $X \times X$.

Now, we'll prove the other direction. Suppose that $D \times D$ is dense in $X \times X,$ and suppose, for a contradiction, that $D$ is *not* dense in $X$. Then, there must exist some nonempty open set $U \subseteq X$ such that $U \cap D$ is empty. Clearly, $(U \times U) \cap (D \times D)$ must also be empty, hence $U \times U$ is a nonempty open set in $X \times X$ whose intersection with $D \times D$ is empty. However, since $D \times D$ is dense in $X \times X$ by assumption, this is a contradiction. So, $D \times D$ being dense in $X \times X$ implies that $D$ is dense in $X$.